# What is a better way to write X increases as Y increases?

Tags: writing

What is a better way to write `X increases as Y increases`?

Two `increases` seem repetitive.

Thanks.

Comment: It completely depends on what idea exactly you want to express. As one possible way to get rid of repetitiveness, you could write something like this: **X increases as Y rises.**

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Thanks. I wonder, instead of change the word, is there any way to reconstruct the sentence?

Comment: Sure, you could say something like this: **As Y increases, X increases.** I would recommend that you take your time and properly state what it is exactly that you want help with.

Comment: “There is a positive correlation between Y and X”.

Comment: "X increases with Y", ...

Comment: Repetition is not ungrammatical, and in situations like this, it is stylistically appropriate.  Let clarity guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tᴚoɯɐuo noted, there really isn't any reason to avoid the repetition. But if you want to, there are plenty of good ways (his own suggestion of "so does" included).

> X increases in proportion to Y.
>   
> *(If you mean that they increase at 1:1 ratio, you can say "exact" proportion.)*
>
> X and Y increase in proportion / in parallel.
>
> X increases with Y.
>
> X and Y increase at the same time.
>   
> *(Again, if the ratio is 1:1, you can say "at the same rate".)*
>
> X's increase is a function of Y's.

...and so on. P.S. Don't forget that the convention is for X to be the independent variable, not Y.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

As Y increases so does X.

> As  pressure increases [**so does**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22increases%20so%20does%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) temperature.

Answer (score 0):

X increases as Y does.

There are alternatives, but I cannot see an alternative to using 'as' if you need to retain the idea that the increases in Y are causing those in X too.